# MySQL - Union in a filtering subquery

Tags: mysql

I'm able to run the following:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM t2);
```

As well as:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM t2 UNION SELECT id FROM t3);
```

But MySQL complains when I attempt to run the following:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM t2 UNION SELECT id FROM t3);
```

The error is "unexpected 'SELECT'" for the third select.
Is something wrong with my syntax? Is this not possible? I'm open to rewriting using `EXISTS` if that's the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not mistakes on your query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/223dbc/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t1 ( id int );
create table t2 ( id int );
create table t3 ( id int );

insert into t1 values (1);
insert into t2 values (2);
insert into t3 values (3);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.id NOT IN
(SELECT id FROM t2 UNION SELECT id FROM t3)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/223dbc/1/0)**:

```
| id |
|----|
|  1 |
```